# ¿Como obtener las etiquetas ID3 de un archivo MP3?

Tags: java

¿Como obtener los argumentos que contienen un archivo **mp3** utilizando código **JAVA**, osea, la información como *el año, título, cantante, año...*?

La cuestión es que lo que pretendo es poder editar esos valores u objetos **ID3** programandolo con java, se que hay programas para ello pero mi idea es hacerlo yo con código.

¿Alguna idea por dónde encaminar mis pasos? Clases utilizar o librerías externas recomendas....

Bueno muchas gracias y saludos....

Comment: Creo que esta es la libreria que andaba buscando...     https://blinkenlights.org/jid3/

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar la librería `jaudiotagger` he aquí algunos [ejemplos](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.jaudiotagger.tag.id3.AbstractID3v2Tag).

```
AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(testFile);
Tag tag = f.getTag();
AudioHeader = f.getAudioHeader();
```

Con la instancia del objeto `Tag` puedes acceder a propiedades como

```
tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ARTIST);
tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ALBUM);
tag.getFirst(FieldKey.TITLE);
tag.getFirst(FieldKey.COMMENT);
tag.getFirst(FieldKey.YEAR);
tag.getFirst(FieldKey.TRACK);
tag.getFirst(FieldKey.DISC_NO);
tag.getFirst(FieldKey.COMPOSER);
tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ARTIST_SORT)
```

Mas info [aqui](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/examples_read.jsp)

De paso también te comparto un proyecto que hice usando esta librería para colocarle imagenes a mis Mp3 que no tenían, te puede servir de guía y para tener una mejor idea de como usar la libreria, proyecto en [Github](https://github.com/ropherpanama/cover-editor). Aclaro que el API usado para descargar las imágenes en ese tiempo, ya no está disponible :)

Comment: Ya me funcionó era un error de importación no me habia pasado nunca eso con eclipse.. muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Este es el programa para editar las etiquetas ID3 de un archivo mp3.

import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFile;

import org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFileIO;

import org.jaudiotagger.audio.exceptions.*;

import org.jaudiotagger.tag.*;

import org.jaudiotagger.tag.id3.ID3v11Tag;

public class edicionEtiquetas {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

new editarmp3();

}

}

class editarmp3{

File archivo = new File("C:/CancionesMp3/cancion.mp3");

AudioFile audiofile = new AudioFile();

ID3v11Tag ide = new ID3v11Tag();

```
public editarmp3(){

    try {

        audiofile = AudioFileIO.read(archivo);

        Tag tag = audiofile.getTag();                   
        FieldKey[] parametro = {FieldKey.ALBUM,  FieldKey.ARTIST, FieldKey.YEAR, 
                  FieldKey.GENRE, FieldKey.TITLE, FieldKey.TRACK,FieldKey.AMAZON_ID 

              };            
        System.out.println(audiofile.getTag());

        tag.setField(parametro[2], "2020");

        System.out.println(audiofile.getTag());
        try {
            AudioFileIO.write(audiofile);
        } catch (CannotWriteException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (CannotReadException | IOException | TagException | ReadOnlyFileException
            | InvalidAudioFrameException e3) {}

}
```

}

Para el interes de alguien en el proximo futuro.

Libreria Enlace:http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjaudiotagger204jar.htm

Gracias y suerte saludos....

Comment: ¡Arregla este formato! :O

Answer (score 0):

quiero saber porque se usa esto:
MP3File arch = (MP3File) AudioFileIO.read();
para que se usa uno y el otro;
AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(), podrias darme muchos detalles en tu respuesta, gracias. Lo que sé, es que muestran las etiquetas ambas clases, por su propios metodos, pero quiero saber si crean ID3 a los archivos mp3 y como, ya que tengo archivos que no tienen ID3. Y lo que tengo pensado es hacer un recorrido a mis 800 archivos mp3 y creale su estructura ID3, para poder llenar informacion.

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/338195)